# В каком типе передавать в xsd схеме данные о числах с логическими операторами?

Tags: xml, xsd

На входе данные о высоте объекта (метры):

- <0,05
- 0,05
- 0,01
- 0,02
- ......
- 5
- 7
- 8
- 8
- 9
- 10
- =>11

Описание:
Формирую xsd схему.

Вопрос:
Подскажите пожалуйста в каком типе передавать в xsd схеме данные о числах с логическими операторами?

*Примечание: вариант string или заводить отдельный SimpleType со значениями логического оператора не подходит.*

Код:

```
<xs:SimpleType name="ВысотаОбъекта">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:какойТипНезнаю???">
    <xs:enumeration value="...">
    <xs:enumeration value="...">
    <xs:enumeration value="...">
```

Код с вариантом решения (регулярные выражения):

```
<xs:simpleType name="ВысотаОбъекта">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0,05-70]|оператор сравнения и число???"/>
    <xs:documentation>&lt;0,05<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>0,05<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>0,1<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>0,2<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>...<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>9<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>10<xs:documentation/>
    <xs:documentation>=&gt;11"<xs:documentation/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Enum универсален для смешанных данных. Возможно поможет [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925706/xml-schema-how-to-restrict-attribute-by-enumeration) решение.

Comment: @Rootware значений перечисления очень много (расписал вопрос свой), поэтому решил поступить иначе, с помощью патерна. Если есть у вас возможность, можете подсказать в части регулярных выражений, какой выражение нужно использовать по вашему мнению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если список значений фиксирован, то подойдет такой вариант

```
<xs:simpleType name="ВысотаОбъекта">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="&lt;5"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="9"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="=&gt;10"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Если нет, то используйте регулярные выражения

```
<xs:simpleType name="ВысотаОбъекта">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="(&lt;?0\,\d{1,2})|((=&gt;)?\d{1,2})"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Немного пояснений по регулярному выражению

- `(&lt;?0\,\d{1,2})|((=&gt;)?\d{1,2})` - допускаются значения удовлетворяющее маскам `&lt;?0\,\d{1,2}` или `(=&gt;)?\d{1,2}`
- `&lt;?0\,\d{1,2}`

  - `&lt;?` - необязательный символ `<`
  - `0\,\d{1,2}` - за ним должен идти `0,` и одна или две цифры после запятой
- `(=&gt;)?\d{1,2}`

  - `(=&gt;)?` - выражение может начинаться символами `>=`
  - `\d{1,2}` - а потом должна идти одна или две цифры

Comment: список значений фиксирован, но он очень большой. поэтому думаю применить вами рекомендованный способ когда список не фиксированный. В регулярке не силен, подскажите пжта. что в моей регулярном выражении не правильно? См. основной вопрос.

Comment: @Kirumit Неправильно все. Вы опишите маску, которую нужно наложить на значения

Comment: маску? Можете какой-либо пример привести подобный моему?

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ, за терпение и подробный и достаточно разжеванный ответ! Респект!

Comment: хочу у вас спросить как у эксперта, можете подсказать ресурс или книгу с помощью которого вы изучили и стали Экспертом в регулярных выражениях?     читаю книгу xml издательства orelly и сайты, но столь подробного разжеванного материала там нет :(

Comment: Читайте регулярки в PHP и JavaScript - там они описаны лучше всего. Регулярные выражения везде примерно одни и те же вне зависимости от языка применения. А в документации по XML они почти нигде не описаны.